# Font CSS missing

Tags: css, font-face

I am not sure what is wrong, but my phone was unable to show my blog post using this font. It reverts back to the standard font used in blogspot again

```
 @font-face{
        font-family: 'citystencilregular';
        src: url('https://www.dropbox.com/s/3p2opgb34hqtabs/citystencil-webfont.woff2?dl=0') format('woff2'),
             url('https://www.dropbox.com/s/0vrf25i02ol7qpz/citystencil-webfont.woff?dl=0') format('woff');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can not. If I use your link, I do not get the font file, but an HTML which offers me download the file to load page.

Get this to work needs the font file being send back, not a html page.
Like here: https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans